# Can't figure how to overload using methods

Tags: java

This what i have so Far, i've been at it for a while and can't seem to figure it out. I would appreciate any help given.

```
public static double average(int NumOne,int NumTwo){
    double Sum;

    Sum =  (((double)NumOne + (double)NumTwo) / 2);
    return (Sum);
}
public static double average(int NumThree){
    double Sum = 0;

    Sum = + (((double)NumThree) / 3);
    return (Sum);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Num1,Num2,Num3;

    System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
    Num1 = Input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
    Num2 = Input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the third number:");
    Num3 = Input.nextInt();

    System.out.print(average(Num1, Num2));
    System.out.print(average(Num3));
}
```

}

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Write a method called average that accepts two integer parameters and returns their average as a floating point value.

Overload the average method of exercise so that the method returns the average of three integers.

Comment: You've successfully overloaded a method. However, the signature of the new overloaded method does not accept three integers, as you specified in a comment. You want `public static double average(int numOne, int numTwo, int numThree )`. [And, by the way, almost universally, variables are lowercase in Java.]

Comment: Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static double average(int NumOne,int NumTwo){
    double Sum;

    Sum =  (((double)NumOne + (double)NumTwo) / 2);
    return (Sum);
}

public static double average(int NumOne, int NumTwo, int NumThree){
    double Sum = 0;

    Sum =  (((double)NumOne + (double)NumTwo + (double)NumThree) / 3);
    return Sum;
}
```

Then in your main:

```
System.out.print(average(Num1, Num2));
System.out.print(average(Num1, Num2, Num3));
```

Comment: But is that overloading since it doesn't break it into 2 separate num one and num 2 print outs?

Comment: Added original `average` method to show they are still two separate overloaded methods.